# change password for devise admin without :registerable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to make Devise Admin not registerable, but when I take `:registerable` away from admin.rb, the `edit_admin_registration_path` does not work. In this case, how can an admin change his email/password?

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :timeoutable, :registerable
```

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `edit_admin_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x8cf7b40>:0x8cf5278>
```

Note: I have 2 different Devise Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `:registerable` from your `Admin` model will remove all route helpers for the `Devise::RegistrationsController`, such as: `edit_admin_registrations_path`.

You will need to keep the `:registerable` in your `Admin` model and override the `Devise::RegistrationsController` to restrict access to `new` and `create` actions.

Create a new `registrations_controller.rb` that contains:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

And in your `routes.rb` tell Devise to use your registrations controller.

`devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }`

This way you will restrict users from creating accounts, but allow existing ones to edit their info.

Comment: Thank you, but If I have multiple devise models (admin, user, guest), will they all be using the same `registrations_controller.rb`?

Comment: I did as you say, created the `class RegistrationsControler < Devise::RegistrationsController`, but it keeps giving an error `Unable to autoload constant RegistrationsController, expected C:/sites/blogger/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb to define it`

Comment: Assuming you have something like this defined:

`devise_for :admins`
`devise_for :users`
`devise_for :guests`

Changing: 
`devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }` will only affect the admin.

Also about the error you are getting. It is a typo in the controller name, that I edited in the original answer.

On a side note, you should consider using something like Rolify and Pundit for role based access instead of duplicating functionality through models, but that's out of scope of this question.